# How to send email with play framework 1.x and Amazon SES?

Tags: playframework, jakarta-mail, playframework-1.x, amazon-ses

I am trying to send email in my `play! framework 1.2.5` app with `Amazon SES`. As I search, I can not define configuration of amazon SES mail in application.conf. And I created a job which set configuration in java. However I am getting the following exception. For whole day, I am trying to make my app send email. But any try failed. I thought you may help me.
I appreciate.

```
@OnApplicationStart
public class Bootstrap extends Job{
    @Override
    public void doJob() throws Exception {
    Properties props = play.libs.Mail.getSession().getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol","aws");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host","email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port","25");
        props.setProperty("mail.aws.user", "...");
        props.setProperty("mail.aws.password", "...");
        System.out.println("AMAZON SES-MAIL PROPERTIES SET SUCCESSFULY");
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
play.exceptions.MailException: Error while sending email
at play.libs.Mail$2.call(Mail.java:186)
at play.libs.Mail$2.call(Mail.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:25
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1242)
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1267)
at play.libs.Mail$2.call(Mail.java:183)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 Authentication required

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1829)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1368)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:886)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:191)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1232)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That my question is not answered. And I found out what my problem was. I explain it so that some others having such problem can benefit from. 
Since the begining, I think my problem was not to define specific ports for outgoing SMTP calls in security-group.
[This](http://support.arpreach.com/support/articles/74761-setting-up-amazon) is a good article you can read. Furthermore no need to configure AWS SES in any bootstrap class. I have just defined it in application.conf as I showed below.

```
mail.transport.protocol=aws
mail.smtp.host=<your aws smpt server name>
mail.smtp.port=587
mail.smtp.user=<your username>
mail.smtp.pass=<your password>
mail.smtp.channel=ssl
```

However mails goes to spam folder and I could not find why it is happing like that. If anbody having any idea about that write a comment here I would appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to connect on port 25 - this port is used for unencrypted email but Google requires that client connections be encrypted. You should use port 587 instead.

FYI, An alternative approach would be to let sendmail do the heavy lifting. Follow [these instructions to configure sendmail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sendmail.html) on your AWS instance.

The edit your Play! application.conf and set:

mail.smtp.host=127.0.0.1

Finally, [have a read of the Play! docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/emails) to see how to send mail from your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did what you told. But I again got the same exception. I have already manage to send email by gmail smtp in my localhost. I think I am doing something wrong with amazon SES configuration. I also could send email through amazon SES interface by verified email addresses. I doubt I may have a mistake about SES and my EC2 instance. Because I didnt do anything for making them to recognize eashother. And I dont know what I should tell you so that you can help

Comment: I have just seen that. why is it still going to port 25 even if I set smtp port to 587?
 Sending the email to the following server failed : email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:25